# Taking multiple header (rows matching condition) and convert into a column

Tags: bash, perl, command-line, awk, sed

Hello I have a file that has multiple Headers in it that I need to have turned into column values. The file looks like this:

```
Day1
1,Smith,London
2,Bruce,Seattle
5,Will,Dallas
Day2
1,Mike,Frisco
4,James,LA
```

I would like the file to end up looking like this:

```
Day1,1,Smith,London
Day1,2,Bruce,Seattle
Day1,5,Will,Dallas
Day2,1,Mike,Frisco
Day2,4,James,LA
```

The file doesn't have sequential numbers before the names and it doesn't have the same quantity of records after the "Day" Header. 
Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this using the command-line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In awk

```
awk -F, 'NF==1{a=$0;next}{print a","$0}' file
```

Checks if the number of fields is 1, if it is it sets a variable to that and skips the next block.

For each line that doesn't have 1 field, it prints the saved variable and the line

And in sed

```
sed -n '/,/!{h};/,/{x;G;s/\n/,/;p;s/,.*//;x}' file
```

---

Broken down for MrBones wild ride.

```
sed -n '

        /,/!{h};       // If the line does not contain a comma overwrite buffer with line

       /,/{            // If the line contains a comma, do everything inside the brackets
           x;          // Exchange the line for the held in buffer
           G;          // Append buffer to line
           s/\n/,/;    // Replace the newline with a comma
           p;          // Print the line
           s/,.*//;    // Remove everything after the first comma
           x           // exchange line for hold buffer to put title back in buffer for the next line.
          }' file      // The file you are using
```

In essence it saves the lines without a `,`, i.e the headers. Then if its not a header, it switches the current line with the saved header and appends the now switched line to the end of the header. As it is appended with a newline, then the next statement replaces that with a comma. Then the line is printed. NExt to recover the header, everything after it is removed and it is swapped back into the buffer, ready for the next line.

Comment: ^1 for the awk answer and a shudder for the sed one :-).

Comment: @User112638726 Could you explain your sed answer?

Comment: @MrBones *please. And what part are you struggling with ?

Comment: With info sed I can bumble my way through it, but its a bit opaque people who come across it who only use `sed s/x/y/` - there's a bunch of cool things happening, and it shows sed off nicely, so it's a nice example to break down :)

Comment: @MrBones There ya go :)

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/^Day/ {h;d;}
     G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/
    ' YourFile
```

- posix compliant
- print nothing if not at least 1 *data* after a *Day*
- white line are treated as *data*

`awk '{if ( $0 ~ /^Day/ ) Head = $0; else print Head "," $0}' YourFile`

- use `Day` as paragraph separator and content as header to use on following line

Comment: This is like my sed, except devoid of all the pointless getting and exchanging. +1!

Comment: yes :-), same for the awk, same principle but test of rupture is on another *value*

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $header;
while (<>) {                # Read line by line.
    if (/,/) {              # If the line contains a comma,
        print "$header,$_"; # prepend the header.
    } else {
        chomp;              # Remove the newline.
        $header = $_;       # Remember the header.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Perl**

```
$ perl -F, -wlane ' if(@F eq 1){$s=$F[0]; next}print "$s,$_"' file
Day1,1,Smith,London
Day1,2,Bruce,Seattle
Day1,5,Will,Dallas
Day2,1,Mike,Frisco
Day2,4,James,LA
```

Comment: You also may want to take off the -w unless you want the warning for an unitialised `$s` to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Another sed version

```
sed -n '/Day[0-9]\+/{h;b end};{G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/;p;:end}'
```

Comment: only {h;b} is enough, it will act like break command if label is not stated +1 for solution

Answer (score 1):

This Perl one-line program will do as you ask. It requires Perl v5.14 or better

```
perl -ne'tr/,// ? print $c,$_ : ($c = s/\s*\z/,/r)' myfile.txt
```

for earlier versions of perl, use

```
perl -ne'tr/,// ? print $c,$_ : ($c = $_) =~ s/\s*\z/,/' myfile.txt
```

**output**

```
Day1,1,Smith,London
Day1,2,Bruce,Seattle
Day1,5,Will,Dallas
Day2,1,Mike,Frisco
Day2,4,James,LA
```

Comment: `-ne'tr` should be a space here ?

Comment: @User112638726: I'm not sure exactly where you mean, but no

Comment: There should be a space between the start of the command and the switches.

Comment: @User112638726: What, like `perl -ne 'tr/,// ...`? That's unnecessary. The "command" is a string parameter to the `-e` switch

Comment: Oh right, didn't know :) Thanks for clearing that up. If i run it though i still get loads of errors such as `Bareword found where operator expected at -e`,`syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/\s*\z/,/r"` and `Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: @User112638726: You're using an old version of Perl. The `/r` modifier on `s///` requires version 5.14 or later

Comment: Ahh right. Might want to mention that on your answer!

Comment: @User112638726: I did :)

Comment: @User112638726: Okay I've added a version for older Perls

Answer (score 0):

Another perl example- this time using `$/` to separate each record.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "Day";

while (<>) {
    next unless my ($num) = m/^(\d+)/;
    for ( split /\n/ ) {
        print "Day${num},$_\n" if m/,/;
    }
}
```